# UIButton is not clickable when it's on top of a MapView

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, mkmapview, clickable

i've searched for quite a bit of time but so far I couldn't find the exact problem.

I've created a mapView in InterfaceBuilder. Trough the click of a button I add another View.

```
self.buttonView = [[ButtonView alloc] init];
self.buttonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.buttonView];
```

In the created buttonView, I create 5 buttons programmatically, like this:

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(25, 275, 100, 30);
[button1 setTitle:@"button1!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:button1];
```

The buttons appear correctly, but they are not clickable. I've tried several things,but nothing seems to work so far. 
Whenever I click on a button, the mapView gets clicked. For example when I double click a button, the mapView zooms in. Both mapView and buttonView are subViews of "view".

I want the buttonView to be on top of the mapView (which it does) and the mapView to scroll underneath the buttonView (which it does), while the buttons stay where they are (which they do), but they are not clickable

Help is greatly appreciated! :-)

EDIT1: Tried `self.buttonView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`- doesn't change anything. (also for the buttons themselves!

Comment: Can you clarify which view you're adding the `ButtonView` to?  Are you wanting this view to float on top of the MapView?  Or are you wanting this view to scroll with the map?

Comment: I'm adding five UIButtons to the buttonView, which is a subView of the standard view. I want the buttonView (with the five buttons) to stay on top of the mapView, meaning only the mapView should scroll ("under" the buttonView), the buttons should stay the same

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you add just a `UIButtonView` instead of `ButtonView`?

Comment: no ... but it should be possible if I add them to another view?!

Comment: I meant to say `UIButtonView`...fixed that...

Comment: buttonView is a custom view.. If I add the button directly into the view, it works. but i want to have the buttons in a separate view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pretty simple mistake, my "upper" view was invisible and denied clicking to buttons underneath :S

Answer (score 1):

I used interface builder and was not seeing the button. I had to set the MKMapView to hidden until the button was displayed and in the right position. Then I set the MKMapView to visible.

Here are the steps I had to take in the interface builder to get my button to show

1. Create a UIViewController which contains a view
2. Add an MKMapView and set constraints

[image: shows a MKMapView in a view controller in IB]

2. Add UIButton in the same view as the MKMapView, set image and text, whatever is applicable. If MKMapView disappear when you try to resize or move the button, the map view has just set its width and height to zero.  Enter new values in the Size Inspector for the map view,and it will resize back.  Or you can move the button elsewhere off the MKMapView and then move the button back to where you want it.
3. The important part is to set constraints for the UIButton.  I set the MKMapView hidden until I got the size and placement right and then set it back to visible.

   [image: shows a UIButton on top of the MKMapView with constraints in IB]

Here's how it looks in the simulator

[image: shows the running app with button on to of map]

Comment: oh, thanks! what a trick with a MapView hidden property, it does work as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is a typo error: You should add subview to self.buttonView right?

```
[self.buttonView addSubview:button1]
```

See it helps

Comment: that's not the problem, it's correct, otherwise you wouldn't see the buttons. the code is in the buttonView's init method, so there is only self, not self.buttonView

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit similar case once, and the solution was

```
[button1 setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

If the view under a control element also handles touch events, the control might work in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cartogaphy I also had to set the height and width constraints similar to @Maria. So the following would not work:

```
categoryButton.addTarget(self, action: "toggleCategoryDropdown:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
categoryButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
categoryButton.userInteractionEnabled = true

self.addSubview(categoryButton)

constrain(categoryButton) {
    categoryButton in

    categoryButton.top == categoryButton.superview!.top + 26
    categoryButton.left == categoryButton.superview!.left + globalConfig.margin
}
```

But this did work

```
categoryButton.addTarget(self, action: "toggleCategoryDropdown:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
categoryButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
categoryButton.userInteractionEnabled = true

self.addSubview(categoryButton)

constrain(categoryButton) {
    categoryButton in

    categoryButton.top == categoryButton.superview!.top + 26
    categoryButton.left == categoryButton.superview!.left + globalConfig.margin
    categoryButton.width == 100
    categoryButton.height == 100
}
```